# Multiple colors in vertical line with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to draw a vertical line with two colors. The first part starting from the top should be colored in red and should take 20% of the total height. The rest should be colored in gray. This is what I attempted to do. It kind of does what I want but I want to overlap the two lines so that the red part hides the gray one in the top of the vertical line:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
  .vline {
    border-left: 6px solid gray;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    left: 50%;
  }

  .vline:before {
    content: '';
    border-left: 6px solid red;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute; 
  }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="vline"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you just need the red line to overlap the grey one? If yes, you can add the property `left: -6px;` to the `:before` element

Comment: read **all** the duplicates, there is vertical AND horizontal